# Why is this Marsh puzzle solution wrong?

Tags: the-witness

Ok, I'm new to the game (under an hour) so bare minimum of spoilers please.

I'm trying to solve the marsh puzzles and from the "tutorial" set, I picked up the following rules...

- The outline must include all the symbols
- The shapes defined in symbols must fit in the enclosed area with no overlap and nothing spare
- The symbols don't have to be on top of respective shapes

This seemed to work for all the tutorial puzzles, but then I tried these rules out on the first puzzle, to extend a bridge.

This didn't work
[image]

But this did
[image]

Why? What additional rule am I missing?

I found the working solution by trial and error and want to understand before progressing

Comment: Hint: The blocks in this puzzle represent something physical in the immediate area...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both solutions are correct for this puzzle.

However, this puzzle controls the movement of the platform you're standing on.  The first solution is for the side you were already on.

If you need to go back across to the other side, you will need to use the first solution.

Comment: On a side note, the Marsh has a few other puzzles like this where the puzzle controls the movement of a platform.  All of them have multiple solutions that move the platforms.

Comment: Also note the colors of the wires.  The white wires are the active ones.

Comment: That makes so much more sense, thank you. It also explains why it wasn't flashing any of the symbols to indicate errors.

Comment: There are a few other similar puzzles in the marsh, as well as a few other places (the quarry, the treehouse, etc).

Comment: @Basic if you input an incorrect solution, the line you drew will fade away; that's how you know that the initial "wrong" solution was actually valid.